# multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'

Tags: winapi, g++, gdi

I was trying to Compiling the code Provided by the Book `Windows Graphics Programming Win32 GDI and DirectDraw` . I am using Dev C++ IDE. Here Goes the Code

```
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <assert.h>

void CenterText(HDC hDC, int x, int y, LPCTSTR szFace,
                LPCTSTR szMessage, int point)
{
  HFONT hFont = CreateFont(
    —point * GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY) / 72,
    0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
    PROOF_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, szFace);
  assert(hFont);

  HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);

  SetTextAlign(hDC, TA_CENTER | TA_BASELINE);

  SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
  SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0xFF));
  TextOut(hDC, x, y, szMessage, _tcslen(szMessage));
  SelectObject(hDC, hOld);
  DeleteObject(hFont);
}

const TCHAR szMessage[] = _T("Hello, World");
const TCHAR szFace[]    = _T("Times New Roman");

#pragma comment(linker, "-merge:.rdata=.text")
#pragma comment(linker, "-align:512")

extern "C" void WinMainCRTStartup()
{
  HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
  assert(hDC);

  CenterText(hDC, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2,
    szFace, szMessage, 72);

  ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
  ExitProcess(0);
}
```

When I compile I get the Following Errors

```
multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup' 
first defined here 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16' 
ld returned 1 exit status 
C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\Win32GDIBasic2\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Win32GDIBasic2.exe] Error 1
```

Comment: The CRT implements WinMainCRTStartup which in turn calls your WinMain function.  If you really want to do what you are trying to do you can use the /entry linker option to provide your own entry point (you should name it something other than WinMainCRTStartup, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages tell you that you've got two `WinMainCRTStartup()` functions, the one you define and the one in the run time to which you are linking.

On the other hand you've not defined `WinMain()` at all. Mehrdad is correct, you should call your main function `WinMain()`.

Are you compiling with the same toolset (compiler, linker etc.) as the book which you are using as a reference?  Different toolsets have slightly different names, although there will always be a main function of some sort or other.

You shouldn't be trying to get your code's main function naming to agree exactly with the book.  You should be getting it to match what your toolset expects.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be redefining `WinMainCRTStartup` unless you specifically need to do that in rare situations (which doesn't seem to be the case here) -- you need [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559.aspx) instead.

Comment: The Book has the Code So I don't Think Its Completely wrong. and Its not a need. Its running a code written in the book

Answer (score 0):

I got this **exact error** while compiling on the **command line**:

**WRONG:**

```
gcc -x c     MyCFile.CustomExtension -o object_file.o -m64 -std=c11
gcc -o EXE.exe                          object_file.o 
./EXE.exe
```

**CORRECT:**

```
gcc -x c  -c MyCFile.CustomExtension -o object_file.o -m64 -std=c11
gcc -o EXE.exe                          object_file.o 
./EXE.exe
```

**DIFF:**

```
-c
```